# Append values to a textbox while clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a calculator using jquery. But i don't know how to append values to the textbox when clicking each calulator buttons. I had tried with the following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=button]").on({
        click: function () {
            var nn = $(this).val();
            $("#text-box-id").val(nn);
        }
     })
});
```

Please help me to solve this scenario.

Comment: please help me in understanding the problem

Comment: i want to write more than number in text box so i take value from button click then write it in text box in every click if i pressed 5 then 6 it is write 6 only i want to write what i all pressed @brk

Answer (score 1):

Concate your value with textbox value to avoid replace.

```
$("input[type=button]").on({
                     click: function () {
                       var  nn =  $(this).val().toString();
                       var txtval=$("#text-box-id").val().toString();
                       $("#text-box-id").val(txtval + nn);
                     }
    })
```

Comment: if i want to make mathematical operation on the result how to make this because the result is Nan @Shree

Comment: Use parseInt() to string  for  mathematical operation.

Comment: i did it 
 console.log (parseInt(result.val()));
the result is what in text box but i still can not apply operations

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand exactly but I think what I understand is that you want to just add more numbers rather than override?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("input[type=button]").on({
             click: function () {
               var  nn =  $(this).val();

              $('#text-box-id').val($('#itext-box-id').val() + nn);

             }
     })
         });
```

Comment: if i want to make mathematical operation on the result how to make this because the result is Nan @David